How to Add "Unedited/Unchanged Files" Scope When Searching in Files in JetBrains IDE (RubyMine)?
I'm using RubyMine, and I want to narrow my search to unedited files only. In the search window, I can see various scopes like "Project Files," "Open Files," etc., but there's no option for Unedited Files.
Here’s a screenshot of my search window for reference:
 
Question is:

Is there a built-in way to add a search scope for unedited files?


Currently there is no such option. Feel free to create feature request on YouTrack: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/projects/IJPL/issues
